# dotnet restore on .NET Framework project not working

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET project with the following in its `.csproj`

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

When I run `dotnet restore project-file.csproj` I get the following:

> Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.

Why is this? I thought the `dotnet cli` could work with non Core projects too?

I have nuget packages that are referenced, so I expect the cli to go and download the nuget packages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`dotnet cli` works properly with .NET Framework only if the project was created from `dotnet new` command. If you create project from Visual Studio the structure of `.csroj` files will be different and you usually cannot run `cli` commands towards them

Comment: Thank you Olegl, that would be why. I am working with a legacy project. So what is my alternative? How can I force a retore of the nuget packages?

Comment: @J86 depends on what tools do you use in your pipeline. Most of the build tools provide APIs to use upon older versions

Comment: Let's say I want to force a restore in Visual Studio, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @J86 you can try to use NuGet cli `nuget restore solutionname.sln`

Comment: how do I know if my project is created from `dotnet new` command or Visual Studio? My project doesn't have `.sln` file, so I think it is not a Visual Studio project. But `dotnet restore` says `nothing to do`

Comment: @ismailsunni csproj file will have specific structure. Same structure as net core csproj.

Comment: Have found it better to just bite the bullet, and do dotnet new mvc etc. and port my code, for the sake of ease of deployment.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio only allows you to run nuget commands from nuget console (package manager console) within Visual Studio itself.

If you want to do nuget restore from command line:

- Download nuget executable from https://www.nuget.org/downloads
  (it is not a installer/package, but actual executable!)
- Save it to a folder of your choice and add it to the PATH.
- Then, as suggested above: nuget restore solutionname.sln (but this time you don't have to run Visual Studio!)

Answer (score 1):

After some search, I found following option and solved my problem. For .Net Framework

```
  msbuild [sln file] -t:restore -p:RestorePackagesConfig=true
```

reference to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/213545/how-can-i-get-msbuild-to-restore-any-needed-nuget