# Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore. Jenkins restore stage not working

Tags: .net, jenkins

I have a dotnet web application to build via jenkins but getting the below error at dotnet restore command:
Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57769387/dotnet-restore-on-net-framework-project-not-working

Comment: But I have to build it via jenkins and not dotnet cli. Can you please help