# Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore for .Net Application

Tags: asp.net-core, coverlet

I have a simple console application which targets ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" and I am using `coverlet` to get coverage when I give command `dotnet coverage collect dotnet test` followed by arguments it says:

```
Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore
```

I am in the folder where test projects are. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How do you create the project  ? From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57769387/dotnet-restore-on-net-framework-project-not-working) we can see "dotnet cli works properly with .NET Framework only if the project was created from dotnet new command. "